# Couldn't find the local location of your OneDrive Issue

Tags: vba, onedrive, xlwings

**Background**

I use xlwings within Excel, I just had this message popping out stating that Xlwings was unable to find the location of my OneDrive; I followed the steps as stated on their [troubleshooting section](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/0.24.9/troubleshooting.html) and was able to solve it partially.I realized that OneDrive needs to be unpaused (this mean synced) to be able to solve it

**Problem**

Is there a way to address this without OneDrive needed to be in sync? I create a lot of "temp" files for some middle-processes and I would like to sync the final result, not those that just get created and deleted afterwards. It is not an algorithm design/flaw, let us say for example I download temp files from the internet, then transform them/append them to a master file and lastly delete them (they only serve to get the data). For this matter I hit the "Pause Sync" temporarly until the process is done, but it seems XlWings pops out the message if OneDrive is paused.

Comment: Can't make total sense of this situation right now, but a probably easy solution would be to copy these files to a local drive for editing instead of pausing the syncing. Once you're done, copy them back to their OneDrive location.

Comment: Also make sure to use the latest version as there was specifically a fix for this mess with 0.25.0: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/onedrive_sharepoint.html

Comment: @FelixZumstein Thank you! I was using 0.23